# Is there a log of the output of "bash install.sh [ ]" available for Ubuntu server?

Tags: wireless, command-line, server, bash, scripts

Following the advice of someone on this site I attempted to update a wireless device driver with:

```
bash install.sh []
```

which I ran while in sudo.

The update didn't work and I'm wondering if some part of the script didn't work.  Is there a log that would identify failure or success of the script to install the driver?

I've looked at the syslog file but didn't see anything relevant there.  There was some feedback while running the script and one line referenced a "127" error but I'm not sure if that is significant based on reading the script.

I'm on an Ubuntu server, no GUI and no Internet as that's the driver that's not working.  I know the hardware is okay because I am running Win 7 on the same hardware without issue.

Basically, at this point I'm interested in finding logs or similar in hope of solving the problem.

Comment: Did you get some output running bash install.sh? Could you post syslog on http://pastebin.com/ and update your question with url? Could you add url of this site you followed?

Comment: will do but it will take me about a day.  Thanks.

Comment: There was output but not captured except that I remember seeing an error "127", whatever that means.  This was why I raised the question about "is there a log", I was hoping that somewhere the output of an install command would get logged but didn't see any mention of the "127" error in syslog so figured it might be in some other log.  I have copied syslog on pastebin as requested but it choked at 500k so I had to limit it to part of Dec 1 and all of Dec 2.  You can find this at: http://pastebin.com/YDKGQYSh  .  As for the URL that I was following, I'll look that up and get back to you.

Comment: Okay, so I looked for the refering URL and can't quite find the exact one.  Suffice it to say, "iwlist wlan0 scan" sees the beacons from the ESSID correctly and I can ping the wlan0 interface from the terminal but not the gateway or anything beyond the gateway.  I got the latest drivers via EDIMAX and attempted to install them with bash install.sh but I'm not sure if it worked right.  After that I did the blacklist step but that only resulted in no wlan0 being seen at all, so I removed that and now I'm back to where I was to start with.

Answer (score 1):

best I could find on my own (and I'm a newbie) was just running 'apt-get check' for a clue as to how things turned out following an install. Also running 'script' prior to running an 'apt-get install' will capture all the output from the command to file so that you don't have to worry about it scrolling away.